# Jquery UI Datepicker not displaying

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

**UPDATE**
I have reverted back to Jquery 1.3.2 and everything is working, not sure what the problem is/was as I have not changed anything else apart of the jquery and ui library versions.

**UPDATE END**

I having an issue with the [JQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). The datepicker is being attached to a class and that part is working but the datepicker is not being displayed.

Here is the datepicker code I am using and the inline style that is being generated when I click in the input box that has the class ".datepicker".

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy'});

display:none;
left:418px;
position:absolute;
top:296px;
z-index:1;
```

If I change the display:none to display:block the datepicker works fine except it dosen't close when I select a date.

Jquery libraries in use:

- jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.2
- jQuery UI 1.8 jQuery UI Widget 1.8
- jQuery UI Mouse 1.8 jQuery UI
- Position 1.8 jQuery UI Draggable 1.8
- jQuery UI Droppable 1.8 jQuery UI
- Datepicker 1.8

Comment: seems display:none and display:block are overriding the show()/hide() methods that datepicker calls.. are you sure there isn't a CSS rule somewhere else that's conflicting?

Comment: The display:none is being generated by the datepicker plugin and there is not css attached it from my stylesheet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it's the css file in the new one doesn't work. Try to include the old 1.7.* css file on your header too, and try again.

Also, did you try to do a .datepicker( "show" ) right after it constructed?

Comment: Had the same issue just now, decided to update my css file to the newest version, and it worked. I had 1.8.16 and now have 1.8.21. Just an addition to this answer.

Answer (score 32):

I was having the same problem, and I found that in my case the cause was the datepicker div for some reason is retaining the class .ui-helper-hidden-accessible, which has the following CSS:

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
 position: absolute !important;
 clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
 clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
}
```

I'm using the google CDN hosted versions of jquery, so I couldn't modify the code or the CSS.  I had also tried changing the z-index without any success.  The solution that worked for me was to set the clip property for the datepicker back to its default value, auto:

```
$('.date').datepicker();
$('#ui-datepicker-div').css('clip', 'auto');
```

Since this specifically targets the datepicker div, there's less of a chance of unintended side effects on other widgets than changing the ui-helper-hidden-accessible class as a whole.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. I'm using Jquery UI 1.8.18 and Jquery 1.7.1 so this is very up to date.

Comment: can you give some example code?  There are all kinds of reasons why it might not have worked.  My first guess would be that these lines are not being called, or that the selectors are not selecting what you would expect them to select.

Comment: I removed the class altogether. `$('#ui-datepicker-div').removeClass('ui-helper-hidden-accessible');` for the same effect.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution is the only one that has worked for me. You are awesome. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me using jQuery-1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.10.2.

Answer (score 26):

This may be helpful to someone. If you copied and pasted your form data (which has the datepicker input box, ensure you **do not** inadvertently copy the **class="hasDatepicker"**

This means your input box should look like this:

```
<input id="dateChooser" name="dateChooser" type="text" value=""/>
```

NOT

```
<input id="dateChooser" name="dateChooser" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker">
```

I made that mistake inadvertently. Removing the class and allowing the jQuery UI call appeared to fix it.

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: Exactly like this.

Comment: I search for so long to find this answer! Bravo.... I thought I was losing my mind.

Comment: Me too.  Thanks!

Comment: The answer is still valid in 2023, my gosh sire i shall forever be indebted to ye for this help. I bid ye good health for the eternity. but alas , I wonder why this is so? why keeping this particular class has caused this behavior?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue: the Date Picker was added successfully (and could even be found in FireBug), but was not visible. If you use FireBug to remove the class "ui-helper-hidden-accessible" from the Date Picker div (ID of: "ui-datepicker-div"), the Date Picker becomes visible and will work like normal.

If you add the following at the very end of your $(document).ready() function, it will apply this to every Date Picker on you page, and make them all work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      //...
      //Put all of you other page setup code here
      //...

      //after setting everything up (including adding all Date Pickers)
      //apply this code to every Date Picker
      $('#ui-datepicker-div').removeClass('ui-helper-hidden-accessible');  
});
```

That was my initial fix. Afterwards, I tried the solution suggested above by Brian Mortenson and it both worked perfectly, and seemed less invasive than removing an entire class from the element. So I modified my code to apply his solution to the method I used (apply at the end of the document setup so that it applies to every Date Picker and does not require repeating):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      //...
      //Put all of you other page setup code here
      //...

      //after setting everything up (including adding all Date Pickers)
      //apply this code to every Date Picker
      $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('clip', 'auto');  
});
```

Hope this helps to get someone unstuck.

EDIT: Fixed a code syntax error.

Answer (score 7):

I've had a similar issue with 1.7.2 versions of jQuery and jQuery UI. The popup wasn't showing up and none of the applicable suggestions above helped. What helped in my case was taking out the class="hasDatepicker" which (as the accepted answer here notes: [jQuery UI datepicker will not display - full code included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820867/jquery-ui-datepicker-will-not-display-full-code-included)) is used by jquery-ui to indicate that a datepicker has already been added to the text field. Wish I found that answer sooner.

Comment: This explaination helped me to realize if you are duplicating form elements which already have the hasDatepicker class the duplicated datepickers will not work.  I had to remove the class from the cloned forms - something like `$("#sibling_"+nextSibling).find('input').removeClass("hasDatepicker");`

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure that you are using the **same version** of jquery-ui 'js' and 'css' files. Sometimes that could be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using JQuery-UI 1.8.21, and JQuery-UI 1.8.22.

Problem was because I had two DatePicker script, one embedded with *jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js* and another one in *jquery.ui.datepicker.js* (an old version before I upgrade to 1.8.21).

Deleting the **duplicate** *jquery.ui.datepicker.js*, resolve problem for both 1.8.21 and 1.8.22.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the z-index of your datepicker css a lot higher (eg z-index: 1000).
The datepicker is probably shown under your original content.
I had the same problem and this helped me out.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the line

.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { position: absolute !important; clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px); }

to

.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { position: absolute !important;  }

and everything works now. Otherwise try upping the z-index as Soldierflup suggested.

Comment: Still didn't work for me. I tried this suggestion, I've tried @brian suggestion, I've checked for matching source versions and setting the z-index. None of these worked. My datepicker displays without any display styling as if it were all transparent except the text.

Comment: @MikeS. sounds like the CSS file that contains the datepicker is not being applied, or other rules are being applied after.  Can you inspect your date picker in your browser's (Chrome's, preferably) dev tools and see the what rules are being applied and from where?  If they're not there, double check that the path to the file is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem that the datepicker-DIV has been created but didnt get filled and show up on click. 
My fault was to give the input the class "hasDatepicker" staticly. jQuery-ui hat to set this class by its own. then it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are having this issue when working with WordPress control panel and using a ThemeRoller generated theme - be sure that you are using 1.7.3 Version of theme, 1.8.13 will not work. (If you look closely, the element is being rendered, but .ui-helper-hidden-accessible is causing it to not be displayed.

Current WP Version: 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

```
* html .ui-helper-hidden-accessible 
{
 position: absolute !important; 
 clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); 
 clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px); 
}
```

This just works for IE, so I apply this hack and works fine on FF, Safari and others.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different problem. With me the date picker would display but the css was not loading.

I fixed it by: Reload the theme (go to jquery ui css, line 43 and copy the url there to edit your themeroller theme) > Resave without the advanced options > Replace old files > Try not to change the urls and see if that helps as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found my solution.

If you are using templates on your view (using Moustache.js, or others...), you must take into account that some of your classes can be loaded twice, or will be created later. So, you must apply this function `$(".datepicker" ).datepicker();` once the instance has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to happen with some themes (cupertino/theme.css) in my case.

And the problem is the .ui-helper-hidden-accessible class which have clip property, like previous users said.

Just Overwrite it and it will be fine

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datePicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-m-d" });
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('clip', 'auto');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the scripts of metro UI css (excellent free metro UI set from http://metroui.org.ua/) , that can clash too.
In my case, this was the problem recently.

So, removed the scripts reference of metro UI (as I was not using its components), datepicker is showing.

But you cant get metro look for datepicker of jQuery-ui

But in most cases, as others mentioned, its clash with duplicate versions of jQuery-UI javascripts.

Answer (score 0):

I have been similar problems. It would launch once and not a 2nd time under different tabs. I used a class instead of an id, and used the same class name everywhere. To me it appears datepicker activates once and the original initialization has to be used everywhere. One can probably code around this with the destroy api, but for me it was easy to simply use the same class everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code, it's working from my side: just test.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>jQuery Datepicker</title>
      <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Enter Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a trick solution. You can use the below codes.

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
/* any options you want */
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('clip', 'auto');
    return [true, '', ''];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just posting because the root cause for my case has not been described her.

In my case the problem was that "assets/js/fuelux/treeview/fuelux.min.js" was adding a constructor .datepicker(), so that was overriding the assets/js/datetime/bootstrap-datepicker.js

just moving the

to be just before the  $('.date-picker') solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem while working with bootstrap modal. I had accidentally set the z-index for `.ui-datepicker` using `!important` which overrides the date picker z-index css attribute on the element. Removing `!important` worked.

Answer (score 0):

When div is fixed, jQuery changes the position to 'fixed' for its datepicker [Check Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyH0F.png)

so, in order to make it work, we can forcefully give position value to "absolute", like this inorder to make this work.

`div#ui-datepicker-div { position:absolute !important; }`