# jQuery UI datepicker will not display - full code included

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am having trouble displaying the jQuery datepicker as shown here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

I believe I downloaded all of the proper files, but to be certain, I started from scratch and ripped the demo site.  Not all of it, but what I believed to be the important parts.  The result is no datepicker to be shown and no javascript errors.  Here is my full code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/base2.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 jQuery(function(){
  jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker();
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="hasDatepicker" />
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Please remove the class **hasDatepicker** from input tag and it should work fine.

```
class = 'hasDatepicker' //Need to remove
```

Comment: Yes, that class name is used by jquery-ui to indicate that a datepicker has already been added.

Comment: The hasDatepicker class is automatically added by jQuery UI when you call datepicker. Putting it in yourself messes things up.

Answer (score 4):

If you look carefully at the source code of [jQuery UI lib](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js) you can see that it uses `hasDatepicker` class inside for datepicker. So, use any other class (even `hasdatepicker` works) but not `hasDatepicker`:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="anyOtherClassName"/>
```

or:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="hasdatepicker"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove
class="hasDatepicker"

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. 
My resolution was to add `z-index`in `.date-picker` of `datePicker.css`

```
.date-picker {
position: absolute;
z-index:1000;/*********** MY Change *************/
font-size: 1em;
color: #CCC;
text-align: center;
cursor: default;

border: 1px solid #444;
border-radius: 2px;
margin: 6px 0;
background: #222;
box-shadow: 8px 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);}
```

That's it!!! And Lo the date picker started displaying.
Hope this helps some one who'd come here for similar issues.