# jQuery not working when including a page using HTML page include

Tags: jquery, css, jsp

In reference with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820867/jquery-ui-datepicker-will-not-display-full-code-included)

We have a header with a date picked component (Jquery and css).  Date picker  works fine when header alone is present. When I try to include another page as a body with this header, date picker is not working.

We are using the date picker mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820867/jquery-ui-datepicker-will-not-display-full-code-included)

When we include another page to the above mentioned code, date picked is not working.

Include command that I use. `<%@ include file="enterClarity.jsp" %>`
There are some form validation java scripts which are present in enterCalrity.jsp page

Edit:

With header alone

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/calendar.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/datepicker_comp_1.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/datepicker_comp_2.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/datepickr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 jQuery(function(){
  jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker();
 });
</script>
<title>Clarity</title>
</head>

<body>

<form id="clarityaction" name="tstest" onsubmit="return true;" action="/metrix/clarityaction.action" method="post"><table class="wwFormTable">
        <table width="100%" border="0" style="height: 616px; width: 1260px;"
            cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="header">
                <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                <B>Welcome Karthik Prabhu D </B>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="header">
                <td align="right" valign="top">your last login was : 2012-06-16 15:33:51.0
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="left" valign="bottom"><td>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="haspicker" /></td></tr>



            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="70%" width="100%">
                    <table width="60%" border="0" style="height: 430px; width: 1206px;"
                        cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table border="0"style="vertical-align: top" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>

                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </table></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td class="footer"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>


    </table></form>





</body>

</html>
```

After inclusion of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/calendar.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/datepicker_comp_1.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/datepicker_comp_2.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/datepickr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 jQuery(function(){
  jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker();
 });
</script>
<title>Clarity</title>
</head>

<body>

<form id="clarityaction" name="tstest" onsubmit="return true;" action="/metrix/clarityaction.action" method="post"><table class="wwFormTable">
        <table width="100%" border="0" style="height: 616px; width: 1260px;"
            cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="header">
                <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                <B>Welcome Karthik Prabhu D </B>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="header">
                <td align="right" valign="top">your last login was : 2012-06-16 15:36:10.0
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="left" valign="bottom"><td>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="haspicker" /></td></tr>



            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="70%" width="100%">
                    <table width="60%" border="0" style="height: 430px; width: 1206px;"
                        cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table border="0"style="vertical-align: top" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../js/tabing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tabjs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/validaionjs.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/tabStyle.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<-- Other page contents -->         

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you give the final html that comes up? maybe some js in the jsp file is causing error.

Comment: _header with a date picked component_ - please explain?

Comment: and also please show your code, preferably the generated markup

Comment: I have edited the post.. Please ref to that...

Comment: What templating engine, if any, are you using?

Comment: your "outer" page--the one loaded first, has incomplete markup. the last table cell with the new "inner" page is not closed.  you also don't close the last table.  was this left out, or did you not enter the complete markup example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code you posted a second complete html file is injected into another one. You have one html page inside the other... definitely no good ;)

```
    !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/calendar.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/datepicker_comp_1.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/datepicker_comp_2.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/datepickr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     jQuery(function(){
      jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker();
     });
    </script>
    <title>Clarity</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form id="clarityaction" name="tstest" onsubmit="return true;" action="/metrix/clarityaction.action" method="post"><table class="wwFormTable">
            <table width="100%" border="0" style="height: 616px; width: 1260px;"
                cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
[...]    
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="../js/tabing.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tabjs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/validaionjs.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/tabStyle.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <-- Other page contents -->
```

Comment: I have used a page include. Hence it is so. I need to have a header page with body page added to it. Is there any other way to do it than the one which I have done?

Comment: The you should use inclusion to include *portion* of markup which is usually shared among different pages. You have to include only the markup needed, without the markup elements already present in your container page.

Comment: The issue is that your body page is being added AFTER the header HTML tags.  You need to strip out the duplicate tags of the body page and insert that into the body.

Comment: I tried removing the duplicate tags from the body page. Still data picked dont work...

Comment: Does your page markup validate? Do you have any error in your javascript console?

Comment: as @mamoo asserted, you should use a wrapper jsp file with all header and footer includes.  then when you are inside a jsp page file, use includes to dynamically enter new elements onto your existing page.