# Jquery UI Datepicker not displaying after logout and login

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I've got a very weird problem. I have an input that use a jquery-ui datepicker:

```
$("#newDate", $container).datepicker();
```

This input is in a SPI (Single page interface) application, that needs login to work with it. Every content is loaded through AJAX.

The component works properly, but if I log out and log in to my application and I click on my datepicker, the component isn't displayed. I mean, the action doesn't show any calendar.

I tried unsuccessfully a lot of things like this:
[Jquery UI Datepicker not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682259/jquery-ui-datepicker-not-displaying)

I've noticed that when everything works, in the "body" is added this container:

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
```

But when it doesn't work this container isn't loaded.

Below show three examples of my code where I use this component:

First:

```
$("#fecha", $contenedor).datepicker();
$("#fecha", $contenedor).click(function(){
    if($("#fecha", $contenedor).val() == ''){
        $("#fecha", $contenedor).datepicker('setDate', (new Date()) );
    }
});
```

In this example the date is loaded in the input but the datepicker component isn't displayed. I tried to use show() function, but I got the same result.

Second:

```
$("#fechaFinEventoDate", $dialogEditarEvento)
.datepicker({
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {                              
        $("#fechaInicioEventoDate", $dialogEditarEvento)
        .datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
}).val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', fechaFin)); 

$("#fechaFinEventoDate", $dialogEditarEvento)
.datepicker(
    "option", "minDate", $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', fechaInicio)
);
```

Third:

```
$("#fechaInicioEventoTime", $dialogEditarEvento).timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    showSecond: false
}).val(getFormatTime(fechaInicio));
```

I've used this libraries, and I load them in the order showed:

```
jquery-1.10.2.min.js,
jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js,
jquery.ui.datetimepicker.js (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)
```

I've tried to work without datetimepicker library but I have the same issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry @MackieeE I don't undertand you very well, could you explain it again please?

Comment: Sorry, I'll post an answer =)

Answer (score 0):

You're re-updating your HTML, thus a new DOM essentially each time you login/logout with your single screen application. jQuery will only find the *first loaded* instance of the DOM with your current selectors. Adjust them to look for the newly appended (Container) DOM Element *each* time.

### Applying `.datepicker()` to an dynamically assigned `<div>`

```
var $datePickerEl = $(document).find('#fecha', $contenedor );
$(document).on('click', "#fecha", function(){
    if( $datePickerEl.val() == ''){
        $datePickerEl.datepicker('setDate', (new Date()));
    }
});
```

### Reassigning `.datepicker()` to same dynamically created DOM Element

Following your example you provided in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6s8U/2), which reloaded the contents of the DOM with a page of information, posed a problem that it was not re-starting the `.datepicker()` initialisation as expected.

It because the new `.html()` reload was wiping out all the `.datepicker()` helper CSS & `<div>`s, but *was* assigning the element with a new ID. By simply appending the content to a container, rather than the entire document **and** removing any instance of the ID and class that remained in the previous instance of the `datepicker()` the example code below successfully creates a new `.datepicker()` on demand.

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script>
    function loadLogin() {
          $('#content').html('<div id="pp">'+ 
                                '<button id="login">Free login</button>'+
                             '</div>').trigger("create");
          loadEvents();
    }

    function loadEvents() {

        $div = $('<h1>Hi!!</h1>' +
            '<input type="text" class="datepick" />' +
            '<button id="logout" style="margin-top: 100px;">Good bye!</button>');

        $("#pp").html($div).trigger("create");

        /** 
         *  Find the newly appended .datepick
         *  && begin the .datepicker init.
        **/
        $datepicker = $(document).find('.datepick');
        $datepicker.datepicker();

        $('#logout').click(function () {
            //Remove the attached id && class.
            $datepicker.removeAttr('id').removeClass('hasDatepicker');
            loadLogin();
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Demo Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/zP9L6/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, MackieeE. I tried your solutions and It still without working. I think like you, the problem is because there is some element on before DOM or some kind of conflict, but I can't find it. I tried with `$('#date', $div).datepicker({showOn:"button"});`. With this code everything works properly but the problem is the calendar is not showed, even using show(), because this container doesn't exist `<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">`. I tried to destroy datepicker and doesn't work.

Comment: If you think it might be a CSS issue, might need to post HTML/css - also, save the `datepicker` as a variable: http://jsfiddle.net/ba8Nj/2/

Comment: I could isolate the code with problem and I've put it here: http://jsfiddle.net/L6s8U/2/

Comment: @user2893720 Fixed.. that took some work x) jsfiddle.net/zP9L6

Comment: Thnaks for your answer but I couldn't solve the problem with your solution. I've added in logout function this code '$datepicker = $(document).find('.datepick'); $datepicker.removeAttr('id').removeClass('hasDatepicker');'. This would solve the problem because It clean instances and generates new ids, but doesn't work. I've create a new snippet http://jsfiddle.net/zP9L6/4/ that is similar to my code but now works. I don't know what is happen and I don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Finaly I give up. The solution I've implemented is to reload the page after logout. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @user2893720 but sorry I wasn't able to help fix it :(