# jQuery datepicker not showing, initialization call is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

My jQuery datepicker has stopped working...it no longer shows the datepicker on click of an input field. There are no console errors.

I already checked for a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682259/jquery-ui-datepicker-not-displaying).

So I tried adding a new CSS style:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">`

That did not help.

Another proposed solution was soo check for a duplicate occurrence of `clip: rect(0 0 0 0);`, but that is not the case either.

I also tried explicitly calling `show()` on the input field after initialization, but that does not help either.

I also inspected the HTML, but I can't find the HTML for the datepicker so I can't even see what classes are assigned and if that is messing things up.

Here's my code:

(I added a breakpoint and the `.datepicker` call is executed.)

```
<input name="ctl00$CPHCenter$tbReservationDate" type="text" maxlength="14" id="tbReservationDate" class="textbox" placeholder="Datum Reservering" style="width:80%;">

<script>
$(function () {
    $("#tbReservationDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', firstDay: 1 });
    //$("#tbReservationDate").show();
});     
</script>
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery before jQuery-ui? Any error in console?

Comment: I had not included jQuery before jQuery-ui...I have now (locally). Also no console errors. But still it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two elements in your html with `id="tbReservationDate"`.

The first one that appears in the `DOM` is the one in the popup (and there the datepicker works). Change the `id` or use a class to initialize the `datepicker`.

Comment: Exactly, I was about to answer that, anyway, html expects id attribute to be unique, that's why jQuery could not select that element. And you are completely right!